# ¿Cómo analizar el contenido de un <iframe> dentro de mi página hecha en PHP?

Tags: javascript, html

Tengo un enlace y hago un simple iframe, como este:

```
<iframe src="URL"></iframe>
```

Necesito conocer el número de `<h1>`s que el iframe contiene y el contenido de estos `Headline 1`. ¿Cómo puedo hacerlo?

Comment: Con `PHP` ? podrías usar la función `file_get_contents` a partir de ahí realizar la búsqueda de la etiqueta especifica.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si el iframe está en tu dominio, puedes acceder a él mediante `iframe.contentDocument` y a partir de allí seleccionar cualquier elemento del DOM.

```
const iframe = document.getElementById('mi-iframe');
const doc = iframe.contentDocument;
const h1 = doc.querySelector('h1:first-of-type');
```

Si el iframe está en otro dominio obtendrás un error al acceder a `contentDocument` porque por cuestiones de seguridad, los navegadores tienen prohibido el acceso al DOM de dominios externos. En este caso puedes hacer algo de scrapping o extraer el HTML mediante una petición:

```
$url = $_GET['url'];
echo file_get_contents($url);
```

El código anterior lee el HTML de la url que le pasas por AJAX. Finalmente, recibes el HTML y creas un árbol DOM mediante `DOMParser#parseFromString`:

```
const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', 'getExternalHTML.php'); // archivo PHP que devuelve HTML
xhr.onload = () => {
  if (xhr.status === 200 && xhr.readyState === 4) {
    const doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(xhr.responseText);
    const h1 = doc.querySelector('h1:first-of-type');
    // manejar el h1
  }
};
xhr.send('url=' + iframe.src);
```

Una vez creado el árbol DOM puedes manejarlo como de costumbre.

Comment: Gracias @gustavogarcia y eso funciona solamente si la otra pagina está en PHP o cualquier archivo ? Esta en otra pagina y no se manejar ajax, pero marco tu respuesta porque resuelve la necesidad.

Comment: La página destino puede ser de cualquier tipo, igual se renderiza en HTML. Usar AJAX es algo muy sencillo; mírate [esta documentación](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX) para que vayas empezando.

Comment: Me funciono a la perfección. Gracias.